# Discord.py Interaction Already Acknowledged

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

[image]The code runs fine up until I click the button and It gives an error (included at top). The script still runs with the error but I need to fix it for hosting purposes. Thanks!

```
class CollabButton(discord.ui.View):

  def __init__(self):
    super().__init__(timeout=None)
    self.add_item(
        discord.ui.Button(label='Accept', style=discord.ButtonStyle.green))


@client.event
async def on_interaction(interaction):
  if interaction.type == discord.InteractionType.component:
    if is_moderator(interaction.user):
      collab_button_view = CollabButton()
      if not interaction.response.is_done():
        await interaction.response.send_message(
            f"Hey {interaction.user.mention}!\nAn admin has accepted the collaboration offer!"
        )
    else:
      if not interaction.response.is_done():
        await interaction.response.send_message(
            "You do not have permission to use this button.", ephemeral=True)


def is_moderator(user):
  #Role name can be changed to anything
  return any(role.name == 'Cadly' for role in user.roles)
```

I tried adding the if statement to verify if the response is done and I'm running out of ideas. Any insight helps!

Comment: Where is the error?

Comment: Sorry just added it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is happening because you are not filtering the desired interactions in the `on_interaction` event. As a result, interactions that are handled in other components are also being received by this event.

It is highly recommended that you define a `custom_id` for the component you want to handle in this event and filter only interactions arising from it:

```py
class CollabButton(discord.ui.View):

  def __init__(self):
    super().__init__(timeout=None)
    button = discord.ui.Button(
        label='Accept',
        style=discord.ButtonStyle.green, 
        custom_id="collab_button"
    )
    self.add_item(button)


@client.event
async def on_interaction(interaction):
  item_id = interaction.data.get("custom_id")
  if item_id == "collab_button":
    if is_moderator(interaction.user):
      if not interaction.response.is_done():
        await interaction.response.send_message(
            f"Hey {interaction.user.mention}!\nAn admin has accepted the collaboration offer!"
        )
    else:
      if not interaction.response.is_done():
        await interaction.response.send_message(
            "You do not have permission to use this button.", ephemeral=True)
```